# How create interval time algorithm?

Tags: php

It is timeline: 12:00am to 11:59pm. Now some user login to page about 7:00am ok, so system will do nothing. And i need to do is split this timeline for 3 parts.

```
1 part : 8:00 am - 11:59 am
2 part : 12:00 pm - 3:59 pm
3 part : 4:00 pm - 7:59 pm
```

If user login in time 9:00 am he can see code and he can put this code to active some function. If user login about 2:00 pm so system show another code  etc etc.

So my idea is create table in database with three intervals and system about midnight will be create new codes for each part:

```
Table
id | interval_start | interval_stop
1 | 8:00 am | 11:59 am
2 | 12:00 pm | 3:59 pm
3 |  4:00 pm | 7:59 pm

Table code
id | id_interval | code
1 | 1 | 432432
2 | 2 | 654553
3 | 3 | 654646
```

So i can set cron and make some PHP file with create new codes. And when user will go to application he see new code. What do You think about this idea ? It will be good and optimal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to calculate the seconds between midnight and the current time, like so :

```
$interval1_start = 60 * 60 * 8; // 8am
$interval1_end = 60 * 60 * 12 -1; // 11:59:59am
$interval2_start = 60 * 60 * 12; // 12pm
$interval2_end = 60 * 60 * 16 -1; // 15:59:59pm
$interval3_start = 60 * 60 * 15; // 15pm
$interval3_end = 60 * 60 * 20 -1; // 15:59:59pm

$init_time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
$cur_time = time();

$diff = $cur_time - $init_time;

if ($diff >= $interval1_start && $diff <= $interval1_end) {
    echo 'code 1';
}
elseif ($diff >= $interval2_start && $diff <= $interval2_end) {
    echo 'code 2';
}
elseif ($diff >= $interval3_start && $diff <= $interval3_end) {
    echo 'code 3';
}
```

[DEMO](http://3v4l.org/3sqMh)

Intervals and codes can be retrieved from database of course, and can be different each day.

Comment: Thank You for help. In demo in php < 5.0.5 is different result :) but i know why.

Answer (score 2):

you can split a date with 86400 seconds, so from 28800 to 43140 it is 8:00 - 11:59, to check if user in that interval you can get current day timestamp and remove from that current timestamp. like:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Riga'); // Don't forget to set correct GMT
// cause server time can be other.

$today = getdate();
$seconds=$today['hours']*3600+$today['minutes']*60+$today['seconds'];
// or use time()-strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))

$intervals=array(
array('start'=>0,'end'=>3600), // 00:00:00-01:00:00
array('start'=>3601,'end'=>7200), // 01:00:01-02:00:00
);

$in_interval=false;
$in_key=-1;
foreach($intervals as $key => $value) {
  if($seconds>=$value['start'] && $seconds<=$value['end']) {
   $in_interval=true;
   $in_key=$key;
   break;
  }
}

if($in_interval) {
  echo 'Visitor is in interval, ID:'.$in_key;
} else {
  echo 'Visitor is not in interval.';
}
```

Comment: Thank You for help. I need test all possibilities

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think this is good idea and now according to code you can show code

Comment: Thank You, i will when i finish.